# Vuetify theme settings not working in Storybook

Tags: vuejs2, vuetify.js, storybook

(Vue version - 2, Vuetify and Storybook - latest)

Consider the following simple button component:

```xml
<template>
  <v-btn round
    color="primary">
    <slot></slot>
  </v-btn>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "test-button",
}
</script>
```

In the App component file, it is invoked like this:

```xml
  <v-app>
    <v-layout column justify-center>
      <v-layout row justify-center align-center>
         <test-button @click="testBtnClicked">
           Click It
         </test-button>
      </v-layout>
    </v-layout>
  </v-app>
```

And the Vuetify setup looks like this in the main.js:

```js
import Vue from 'vue';
import 'vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css';
import Vuetify from "vuetify";
import colors from 'vuetify/es5/util/colors';

Vue.use(Vuetify, {
  theme: {
    primary: colors.indigo.base,
    info: colors.blue.lighten2,
    accent: colors.green.lighten1,
    error: colors.red.darken2
  }
});
```

So far, so good - I get a nice indigo button in the middle of the frame, which is what I would expect.

Now, in the Storybook config, I'm using the same lines as in main.js to set up Vuetify, and my Storybook file looks like this:

```js
import { storiesOf } from "@storybook/vue";

import TestButton from "./TestButton.vue";

storiesOf("TestButton", module)
  .add("button template", () => ({
    template: '<test-button :rounded="true">round</test-button>',
    components: {TestButton}
  }))
```

This renders the button in Storybook, but the theme settings don't happen, to wit: the button is not indigo, it is white.  The rest of the Vuetify attributes seem to be fine - it looks like a Vuetify rounded button, with white text.

I'm not sure if this is a Vuetify issue or a Vue issue or a Storybook issue (or a user-error issue on my part).  If anyone has done this, I'd appreciate some insight.

Here's my webpack.config.js (in .storybook):

```js
module.exports = (baseConfig, env, defaultConfig) => {

  defaultConfig.plugins.push(new VueLoaderPlugin());

  return defaultConfig;
};
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have the problem too.

After reading vuetify's code, seems the generation of CSS, and injection of the theme is made in the `VApp` mixin `app-theme` located here.

So, I think the problem is not linked to storybook, but vuetify instead.

By wrapping the component I wish to test with a `v-app`, it's ok.

So, for now, please try to add a decorator in your config.js like this :

```js
import { configure, addDecorator } from '@storybook/vue';
import 'vuetify/dist/vuetify.css';

import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuetify from 'vuetify';

Vue.use(Vuetify, {
  theme: {
    // your colors
  },
});

addDecorator(() => ({
  template: '<v-app><story/></v-app>',
}));
```

...

Sounds ok for you ?

(answer too on github : https://github.com/storybooks/storybook/issues/4256#issuecomment-440065778)

Comment: Nice.  Thanks for your effort.  I feel like maybe I can use Storybook, now.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the issue a few months ago so its the not freshest in my mind. You need to import the plugin that adds Vuetify to Vue. Here is the `config.js` file in my `.storybook` folder.

```js
// #### /.storybook/config.js
import { configure } from '@storybook/vue';

import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuex from 'vuex'; // Vue plugins
import '@/plugins/allPlugins';

// Install Vue plugins.
Vue.use(Vuex);

const req = require.context('../src', true, /\.stories\.js$/)

function loadStories() {
  req.keys().forEach((filename) => req(filename))
}

configure(loadStories, module);
```

plugins/allPlugins

```js
import Vue from 'vue'; // <---- important 
import './vuetify'; // <---- important 


import WebCam from 'vue-web-cam';
import Chat from '@/libs/vue-beautiful-chat/index';
import './styles';

import './ellipsis';
import 'viewerjs/dist/viewer.css';
import Viewer from 'v-viewer';

Vue.use(WebCam);
Vue.use(Chat);
Vue.use(Viewer);
```

plugins/vuetify

```js
import Vue from 'vue';
import {
  Vuetify,
  VApp,
  ...
} from 'vuetify';

import colors from 'vuetify/es5/util/colors';

Vue.use(Vuetify, {
  components: {
    VApp,
    ...
  },
  theme: {
    primary: colors.blue.lighten1,
    ...
  },
});
```

The reason I separated out all plugins was because of custom styles and other plugins that I was more control of when importing. If you need custom styles you will need to import both `Vuetify` plugin and custom styles.

Comment: 'k, looks like the relevant thing for me is that you're using the 'a-la-carte' install. Modifying for that, I'm getting the following error:

ERROR in ./node_modules/vuetify/src/stylus/components/_progress-circular.styl
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '@' (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| @import '../bootstrap'
|

Comment: Did you have to make any webpack changes/additions?

Comment: Can you post your `storyboard/webpack.config.js`?

Comment: Added in original message.

Comment: I've gone ahead and entered an issue with the Storybook folks here: https://github.com/storybooks/storybook/issues/4256.  See if they have anything to say about it.